# Extract data from one shapefile based on another

Tags: qgis, extract

I am using QGIS 3.16.1.  I'm trying to find a way to have it tell me what the most common soil type is in a field boundary.  I have downloaded the soil information from NRCS's web soil survey site and have it loaded into QGIS.  In order to save time trying to eyeball what is the predominant soil type, I would like it if there was a way to have QGIS summarize either what soil type is most common or even a list of what is in each field.  I don't really know where to start, as I'm still a newbie.
[image]

Comment: Your question is likely to get closes because it lacks focus.  Still, have a look at the processing tool called Join Attributes by Location.  You would join your soils to your zones, calculate the area for each resulting soil polygon.  Sort the resulting table by zone and soil area.  See this tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: Thanks!  That was basically what I needed, some direction on where to start.  I figured there had to be a way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Intersection` and set the grid polygons as `input layer`, your soil polygons as `overlay layer`:

[image]

On the next screenshot, you see the output you get, containing all the attributes from both layers. You can now calculate the area of each of the new polygons using field calculator with `$area` or `area ($geometry)`.

[image]

Now you can use select by expression to select for each grid cell the largest polygon  by area using this expression: `area = maximum ( "area", "id" )`. `"area"` is the field containing the area you calcultated above, "id" is the unique identifyer of the original grid cells.

As you see in the screenshot: selected (highlighted in yellow) are those polygon parts that have the largest area for each grid cell:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This helps also!